# For Looping Over Dictionary Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, key-value

I have a Python dictionary with the following form:

```
data = {'2022-01-01': [123, 456], '2022-01-02': [789, 120], ... }
```

I am trying to loop over the dictionary data and divide the two numbers contained in the lists (e.g. `123/456`, `789/120`, etc.) with the following:

```
for values in len(range(data)):
    ratio = values[0]/values[1]
```

But I get a `TypeError` saying that the `dict` object cannot be interpreted as an integer. My numbers are clearly integers. Is this not the correct way to loop across a dictionary?

Also, is there a way that I can store the resulting `ratio` along with the `dates` in either a new dictionary or a pandas data frame?

Comment: When you researched iterating over a `dict`, what ways did you find of doing that?

Comment: data is a dictionary. you are calling data like it is a function(it is not callable). Try using `values` variable which is defined in the loop using `items` function on the dictionary.

Comment: @quamrana I get the same error with this method: ```for values in len(range(datesUserRisk)):
    ratio = values[0]/values[1]```

Comment: So, does that indicate to you that you aren't using one of the valid ways of iterating over a `dict`?

Comment: why are you doing `for values in len(range(data))`? What do you think that does? For starters, `len` returns an `int` always, so `for values in some_int` would never work, since `int` objects are not iterable. Usually you mean `range(len(data))`, but in this case, that would iterate over a `range` object, not a dictionary... Have you looked up how to iterate over a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is a dictionary, not a function, so you shouldn't use parenthesis to attempt to access it.

You should also be iterating over `data.items()`, not `len(range(data))`. You're iterating over the keys of a dictionary, not a list.

With these two corrections, we get the following:

```py
for key, values in data.items():
    ratio = values[0]/values[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also worth mentioning:

`len(range(data))` is just a number. `for key, value in 123` (for instance) does not make sense. To iterate the `key, value` pairs of a dictionary (named `data`), you need to do `for key, value in data.items()`.

You don't need the `key`s in order to produce your desired output, so there's no need to iterate the `key, value` pairs, just the `value`s. To iterate just the `value`s, do `for value in data.values()`.